# I accidentally deleted LaunchImage from Xcassets help? How to restore LaunchImage to xcassets

Tags: ios, xcasset

I was editing some files in Xcassets and accidentally deleted the LaunchImage fileset. How do I get it back!?

I tried looking in the target, and the option to use xcassets as the image-containing folder is not there anymore.

Comment: Bad question, +1 for a good answer.

Comment: Yes, a nice answer indeed. However, it could also address the strong recommendation of using a version control system, then you could just hit reset/revert after having done something accidentally :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I looked around for a question that *specifically addressed this issue and couldn't find one.

Here's what you do:

- Right click in the white space under the existing image folders
- (OR) click on the "+" at the bottom of the area
- Now select "New Launch Image"

[image]

This will bring back the original launch image options with all the many, many new image sizes that Xcode 5 and iOS 7 need.

Like this:

[image]